# Do we need both cluster and clustering tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have both a [cluster](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cluster) and [clustering](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clustering) tag.  There is no tag wiki with guidance for either of them.

Do we need both tags?  If we do, how should we choose which one to use on any particular question?

Or should they be merged?

Taking a glance through questions with those tags, it looks like there is no clear distinction between how they are being used, which makes me suspect we should perhaps make [cluster](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cluster) a synonym of [clustering](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clustering).  Any thoughts or analysis?

Comment: I think cluster is more about networking not clustering in ML.

Answer (score 6):

Cluster is allocation unit, coupled together computers or parallel file system. 34 questions use it, none properly. Moreover using definitions I know, properly tagged question would be off-topic. Proper place for such might be [at superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cluster).

Algorithm like k-means performs "clustering" to partition the given set into "clusters" (or groups) - but one cluster is not interesting if someone already found it.

In my humble opinion "cluster" should be replaced by "clustering" ang get deleted, since people used it interchangeably (or starting to write tag selected the first option).

Comment: Should we introduce a more clear tag for clusters of PUs, e.g. [computation-cluster]? Of would you say that [distributed-computing] is enough?

Comment: @Raphael Shortly it is enough, and there are no questions that fit the description or really need it (4 pages, 50Q per page) [distributed-computing] is used by the majority of questions, even questions that seems to be about clusters were either closed or gave it as a background to ask about asynchronous algorithms. [This question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23690/what-are-the-models-of-distributed-storage-systems-in-the-literature) might have used "cluster" but it didn't. It used [distributed-systems] which is well understood.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to say that the 34 questions that all use the tag "cluster" in the same way are using it wrongly. Obviously, they're using it the right way, and the right way is a duplicate of "clustering". So +1 for your final paragraph.

Comment: There are some (probablyappropriate) questions that could be tagged with `[computation-cluster]`, e.g: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/149/50003, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/43389/50003, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/49521/50003, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2784/50003, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/3138/50003.

Comment: @manlio you are right, maybe you could put this as answer or separate topic?

Comment: @Evil I'm not sure about the best course of action.  A `[computation-cluster]` tag can be introduced later. Meanwhile +1 for your proposal.

Comment: FWIW, as of today there is not a single question tagged [tag:cluster] that is about clusters of machines.  If we have any, they use other tags already. (cc @manlio)